# Drupal 7 Incorrect spam bot errors on different browsers

Tags: drupal-7

one website is getting botcha errors on a contact form but on different browsers depending on which Platform is being used.
I have tried iMac, iPhone and iPad with different browsers (Safari, Chrome, Firefox).
I haven't done much maintenance recently so I am not sure how to proceed.